# How to correctly concatenate messages correctly in an alert

Tags: jquery

I want to concatenate messages in my alert so that it show all error messages for the first question it encounters errors on. For example if I have 3 questions and there are errors in question 1 and question 3, when I click on the submit button, the validation alert should display an example alert like so:

> You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0

It is only after I have solved errors in question 1 that when I submit the page again then it shows the alert for question number 3 as an example below:

> You have errors on Question Number: 3
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0

The problem I am having is that it is only showing 1 question number at a time which is fine but it is showing all of the errors from question 1 and 3 so it looks like this below:

> You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0

My question is then how can I get the alert working so it matches the way I want it to work?

Below is the jquery code:

```
function validation() {
    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {  
        var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text()); 
        var txtinput = $(this).val(); 
        _qid = questions;
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

        if (txtinput == '') {
            alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
        }

        if(marks < '0') {
            alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
        }

        if(marks > '0') {
            alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
        }
    });

    //comment
    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the above code where it says `//comment`, if I include this code:

```
if (alertValidation != "") {
    return false; //Stop the each loop 
}
```

Then what it does is that it displays only one message per alert per question e.g

except alerting:

> You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0

It will just alert:

> You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox

```
   UPDATE:
```

Below is an update of the code:

function validation() {

```
    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {  
    var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
    var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text()); 
    var txtinput = $(this).val(); 
    _qid = questions;
    alertValidation += "\nYou have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


if (txtinput == '') {
    alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
}    


if(marks < '0')
{

 alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
}

if(marks > '0')
{

 alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
}



        });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
       alert(alertValidation.substr(1));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But the problem is that below is what it alerts:

> • You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   You have errors on Question Number: 1
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0
>
> • You Have 5 Marks RemainingYou have errors on Question Number: 2
>
> • You have errors on Question Number: 3
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0
>
> • You Have 5 Marks RemainingYou have errors on Question Number: 3
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
>   You have errors on Question Number: 3
>
> • You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox

Comment: Don't use `alert` for this, it's very limited. Use a modal window.

Comment: @elclanrs But an alert must still be able to do the job, shouldn't it? It is just that in my application, in all other pages I have used alerts so thats why I want to keep it to alerts for validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resetting the `_msg` in every `.each()` iteration. If you just add the `_msg` portion of the message to `alertValidation` on a question by question basis, it should be ok.

Not sure if this code will work as I don't have a test page.

```
function validation() {

    // only keeping track of the final message
    var alertValidation = "",
        // toggle for showing only one error
        showOnlyOneError = true;

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {  
        var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + (i+1) + "_ans_text]").text(), 10); 
        var txtinput = $(this).val(); 

        // the message for this question
        var msg = '';

        if (txtinput == '') {
            msg += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
        }

        if (marks < 0) {
            msg += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
        } else if (marks > 0) {
            msg += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
        }

        // if there is an error for the question, add it to the main message
        if (msg.length) {
            alertValidation += alertValidation.length ? '\n\n' : '';
            alertValidation += "You have errors on Question Number: " + questions + "\n";
            alertValidation += msg;
            // stop if we only care about the first error
            return !showOnlyOneError;
        }
    });

    // show the error messages
    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Edit: Fixed a bug with the `parseInt(...)` statement.

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/85/)

Comment: @user1881090 Thanks. I put in a fix re showing more than one error even if `showOnlyOneError` is `true`. Is it otherwise working, correctly? Kinda hard to tell...

Comment: @user1881090 I found a bug with the `parseInt()` statement. The answer is updated. Also, I don't actually understand the way the validation rules are working. Is there a logic error? (I'm going to delete some of my earlier comments that are no longer relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
_msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";
```

That will overwrite any existing text. So what you need to do is write all text into a single variable (instead of `_msg` **and** `alertValidation`) and always append:

```
alertValidation += "\nYou have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";
```

and then

```
alert(alertValidation.substr(1));
```

Comment: Can I ask what substr(1) do in the above example

Comment: I think I am doing it incorrectly. I Included an update in my question which shows the current code with the attempt of matching the changes you have stated and it shows the current alert output

Comment: re substr(1): If you always append, then you will have an extra `\n` (newline) at the start of the message ... unless you forgot to put it into the `You have errors` string, of course.

Comment: Wow this is getting more difficult, realised that I can't store `alertValidation += "\nYou have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";` because if a question has no errors, it will still display the above line for a question number which has no error. Again it is also showing errors for both question numbers. It should only show errors for first question number that contains errors only i.e question 1 only in update